# Unable to resolve the request in Yii using modules

Tags: php, yii

This is my controller

```
class CarsController extends Controller {
    public function actionIndex() {
       echo 1; exit();
    }

}
```

this is the module file:

```
<?php

class CarsModule extends CWebModule {

    public $defaultController = "cars";

    public function init() {
        // this method is called when the module is being created
        // you may place code here to customize the module or the application
        // import the module-level models and components
        $this->setImport(array(
            'cars.models.*',
            'cars.components.*',
        ));
    }

    public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action) {
        if (parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)) {
            // this method is called before any module controller action is performed
            // you may place customized code here
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

my problem is if I access my project like: localhost/cars it works. If I access localhost/cars/index I am getting this message: **Unable to resolve the request** . If I create a new function and I access like this: localhost/cars/myfunction, still  the same. I am working on Windows. Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the default url rule for modules is `module/controller/actin`, so for access `actionIndex` inside `CarsController` inside `CarsModule`, your url should be **localhost/cars/cars/index**, not **localhost/cars/index**. If you don't like the url be like **localhost/cars/cars/index**, you can write one url manager rule to map **localhost/cars/cars/index** into **localhost/cars/index**. Something like this:

```
'cars/index' => 'cars/cars/index'
```